# I m trying to fetch total in to TextBox5.text but error occured

Tags: vb.net

I m trying to fetch total in to TextBox5.text but error occured like No value given for one or more required parameters.

Try
            con.Close()

```
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Pradnya_DataB.mdb"

        con.Open()

        ss = "Select total from stock_bottle WHERE Bottle_type=" & Convert.ToString(TextBox3.Text.ToString())

        cmd = New OleDbCommand(ss, con)

        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If rd.Read() Then

            TextBox5.Text = rd("total").ToString()

        End If

        con.Close()
        rd.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Check your table if you really have columns named exactly _Total_  and _Bottle_type_

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when one or more of your column names and table name are not spelled correctly. In your case, this means that `Total` or `Bottle_type` or even `Stock_Bottle` are not the correct name for your fields or table.

Saying that, and pending the due correction to your query, I suggest you to use a more robust code like this one

```
Try
    Dim ss = "Select total from stock_bottle WHERE Bottle_type=@btype"
    Using con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Pradnya_DataB.mdb")
    Using cmd = new OleDbCommand(ss, con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@btype", OleDbType.Int32).Value = TextBox3.Text
        Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        If result IsNot Nothing Then
            TextBox5.Text = result.ToString()
        End If
    End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Here I have changed your query to a parameterized query. [It is more safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and robust about the correct interpretation of the DataType used for your where clause. 
I have also removed the global variable for the connection. (You don't get any advantage and you need to constantly check for the status of that connection).
I have added the [Using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to ensure proper closing of connection and the immediate release of the system resources kept by the connection.

Finally, if you need to retrieve just one row with one single column then do not use the more expensive `OleDbDataReader` (useful when there are many rows and columns to read back) but directly the OleDbCommand with its [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: and don't forget about the removal of meaningless vb.net code (i'm talking, of course, about the `Convert.ToString(TextBox3.Text.ToString())` instead of simply `TextBox3.Text`)

Comment: Yes, forget about that. TextBox3.Text is already a string, so all that conversion to/from a string is exactly _meaningless_